# Elasticsearch results accuracy not as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have implemented elastic search in rails for fulltext searching in the product database, but it does not return results I would expect.

For example when I search for "samsung galaxy s5" mobile phone, I get mostly cases and not mobile phones. I tested other eshops and when I search for the same words, I get mostly results for mobile phones.

Any recommendation to improve the searching results so it behaves as usual eshop when searching for products?

This is my current search query:

```
def self.search(query)
__elasticsearch__.search(
  {
    size: 1000,
    query: {
      filtered: {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['manufacturer^2', 'en_product^10', 'ma_product^10', 'cs_product^10', 'ma_description', 'cs_description', 'en_description', 'ma_specification', 'cs_specification', 'en_specification']
          }
        },
        filter: {
          term: {
            active: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
}
)
end
```

And mappings:

```
 settings index: {
number_of_shards: 1,
analysis: {
  filter: {
    trigrams_filter: {
      type: 'ngram',
      min_gram: 2,
      max_gram: 10
    },
    content_filter: {
      type: 'ngram',
      min_gram: 4,
      max_gram: 20
    }
  },
  analyzer: {
    index_trigrams_analyzer: {
      type: 'custom',
      tokenizer: 'standard',
      filter: ['lowercase', 'trigrams_filter', 'asciifolding']
    },
    search_trigrams_analyzer: {
      type: 'custom',
      tokenizer: 'whitespace',
      filter: ['lowercase']
    },
    english: {
      tokenizer: 'standard',
      filter: ['standard', 'lowercase', 'content_filter']
    },
    czech: {
      tokenizer: 'standard',
      filter: ['asciifolding','standard','lowercase','content_filter' ]
    }
  }
}
} do
mappings dynamic: 'false' do
  indexes :active, type: 'boolean'
  indexes :manufacturer, index_analyzer: 'index_trigrams_analyzer', search_analyzer: 'search_trigrams_analyzer'
  indexes :en_product, index_analyzer: 'english', search_analyzer: 'english'
  indexes :ma_product, index_analyzer: 'czech', search_analyzer: 'czech'
  indexes :cs_product, index_analyzer: 'czech', search_analyzer: 'czech'
  indexes :en_description, index_analyzer: 'english', search_analyzer: 'english'
  indexes :ma_description, index_analyzer: 'czech', search_analyzer: 'czech'
  indexes :cs_description, index_analyzer: 'czech', search_analyzer: 'czech'
  indexes :en_specification, index_analyzer: 'english', search_analyzer: 'english'
  indexes :ma_specification, index_analyzer: 'czech', search_analyzer: 'czech'
  indexes :cs_specification, index_analyzer: 'czech', search_analyzer: 'czech'
end
end
```

## My results:

[image]

## Other eshop

[image]

Thank you,
Miroslav